# Extract base64 encoded part from an inline embedded image

Tags: php

Say I have an inline embedded image like below

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Is there any php function which can be used to extract base64 encoded data minus (data:image/png;base64, part)?. Any help with an example would be very nice for me. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code? What's the problem with that code? If you haven't got any code: What particular problem is stopping you from writing it?

Comment: the `data:image/png;base64` and the rest of the code is only separated by a coma (,). you can use `explode` to separate the data

Comment: @zimorok thanks for the lead, now I think I can do the rest. I just needed a little push.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$html = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4///w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />';

$start = 'base64,';
$tmp = substr($html, strpos($html, $start) + strlen($start));
$base64 = substr($tmp, 0, strpos($tmp, '"'));

echo $base64;
```

outputs `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4///w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`